# How do I access variables of a host using dynamic inventory in a MongoDB database using Ansible playbook?

Tags: mongodb, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to generate initial configurations using information stored in MongoDB. I am using the dynamic inventory feature with Ansible. The backend is a simple mongodb database. When manually running `ansible_fetch_mongodb.py --list`, it returns groups and their variables/children in JSON as per Ansible's requirements. Using the `--host <hostname>` argument also returns hosts and their variables with no issues. However, when trying to access the variables, say `item.hostname`, or `item.var2` within an Ansible playbook, it errors out and tells me that `item.hostname` isn't defined. I'm using `ansible-playbook build_configs.yml -v -i ansible_fetch_mongodb.py` command to run it all. I have been working for hours on this issue and any help with proper syntax to access variables from a dynamic source is very appreciated.

Here is the playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost 
  tasks:
  - name: configuration generator 
    template: 
      src=roles/core_router/templates/3850.j2
      dest=/etc/ansible/generated_templates/{{ item }}.txt
    with_inventory_hostnames: all
  - debug: msg="{{ item.data1_svi_ip }}"
    with_inventory_hostnames: all
```

Here is the host represented in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": "ROUTER123",
    "hostname": "ROUTER123",
    "vars": {
        "data1_svi_ip": "10.19.83.254 255.255.254.0",
        "device_num": "01",
        "device_type": "Router",
        "floor": "04",
        "grp_ip": "10.19.93.14 255.255.255.240",
        "mgmt_net": "10.19.103.254 255.255.254.0",
        "model": "3850",
    }
}
```

Here are the groups represented in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": "Router",
    "children": [],
    "hosts": [
        "Router123",
    ],
    "name": "Router",
    "vars": {}
}
```

Here is the error:

> TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'ansible.vars.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'data1_svi_ip'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/build_configs.yml': line 8, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    with_inventory_hostnames: all\n  - debug: msg=\"{{ item.data1_svi_ip }}\"\n    ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with_inventory_hostnames` lookup plugin returns the names of the hosts. They are strings, not objects, so Ansible reports: `no attribute 'data1_svi_ip'`.

To access host variables, you need to use:

```
- debug:
    var: hostvars[item].data1_svi_ip
  with_inventory_hostnames: all
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks techraf!

Comment: Nice! I have not known it yet. Thanks a lot!